# After a couple of successful POST requests fetch throws TypeError: Network Request Failed

Tags: node.js, react-native, fetch

I've a weird issue. My issue is that after executing a POST request with fetch a couple of times in a row, it throws an error: TypeError Network Request Failed. But those couple of times that I execute the fetch, they work as they should. I don't get this error with GET requests, no matter how many times I execute those.
For example when I register 7 times, this error is being thrown. Or when I login, logout, login etc. for a couple of times, this error is thrown in.
An example of my POST request with fetch is of registering:

```js
handleRegistration = async (name, email, password) => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch(fetchUrl + ':3000/newCustomer', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    Accept: 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    "name": name,
                    "email": email,
                    "password": password
                })
            });
            const data = await response.json();
            return await data.success ? FadeToast(data.message) && this.props.navigation.navigate('Login') : FadeToast(data.message);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err, 'Register err');
            FadeToast('Server fout');
        }
    };

// NodeJS code
app.post('/newCustomer', function(req, res)
{
    if (!req.body.email || !req.body.password) {
        return res.json({success: false, message: 'Voer alstublieft uw e-mail en wachtwoord in'});
    } else {
        const name = req.body.name;
        const email = req.body.email;
        const password = req.body.password;
        const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
        const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt);

        if(name.length > 50) {
            return res.json({success: false, message: 'Limiet naam is 50 char.'});
        } else {
            if(email.length > 191 || password.length > 191) {
                return res.json({success: false, message: 'Max. characters is 191.'});
            } else {
                if (validateEmail(email)) {
                    createUser([name, email, hash], (err) => {
                        console.log(err);
                        if (err) return res.json({success: false, message: 'E-mail al in gebruik'});
                        return res.json({success: true, message: 'Succesvol geregistreerd'});
                    });
                } else {
                    return res.json({success: false, message: email + ' is geen geldige e-mail'});
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I use NodeJS to handle the requests. I'm clueless as how to debug this, I haven't seen anyone else with this issue, so any help is appreciated. Also I have tried adb logcat *:E, but this doesn't seem to show anything related to database/react-native or anything. Maybe I am not looking for the right thing in this log, but I don't see anything that could be of use. UDPATE: What appears to go better is adding connection.release() in the cb of the query, only this doesn't prevent the error, it only seems to delay it. Because when I add it, I get the error after even more executions of the fetch request. Maybe this has something to do with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What apparently caused this error was because I didn't have connection.release() in the cb of the query. Which I suppose is necessarily to have it work properly, which is also the code flow I found out in the docs https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql. "This is a shortcut for the pool.getConnection() -> connection.query() -> connection.release() code flow."

```js
const  findUserByEmail  = (email, cb) => {
    db.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        db.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?',[email], (err, row) => {
            connection.release();
            return cb(err, row);
        });
    });
};
```